# Создание с последующей записью в текстовый файл в цикле

Tags: delphi

Подскажите люди добрые как мне решить такую задачу в Delphi, хочу сократить код если конечно так возможно как я хочу

Моя задача в цикле создать 21 файл одним циклом, а не писать кучу повторяющегося кода как например внизу

Пример:

```
Assignfile(AFile, ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'@a.txt');
Rewrite(AFile);
Closefile(AFile);
Assignfile(BFile, ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'@b.txt');
Rewrite(BFile);
Closefile(BFile);
....
```

решение было такое

```
var
  Tfile: array [0..21] of TextFile;  //создание массива для создание файлов
  A: array [0..21] of string; // создание массива для имен файлов

//заполнение массива именами 
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 A[0] := '@a';
 A[1] := '@b';
end;

//создание файлов с нужными именами<br>
procedure TForm1.StartClick(Sender: TObject);
var 
  j: integer;
begin
  for j := 0 to 20 do
  begin
    Assignfile(Tfile[j], ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+ A[j] + '.txt');
    Rewrite(Tfile[j]);
    Closefile(Tfile[j]);
  end;
end;
```

теперь к проблеме как теперь записывать данные в созданные файлы

```
Append(Tfile[A]);
Writeln(Tfile[A],Filez.Strings[num_theards]);
Closefile(Tfile[A]);
```

я понимаю что там должен быть string, а я индекс передаю и типы не совместимые массив со string'ом, как можно это решить?

Comment: Если файл текстовый, то удобнее TStringList использовать. .Add добавить в него строку, есть метод SaveToFile(filename). Перед SaveToFile ставьте Try except.. LoadFromFile - прочитать файл. Короче удобнее в разы, не говоря про то, что там есть сортировка и поиск внутри TStringList.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил, посидев немного, поразмыслив

```
Append(Tfile[A]); 
Writeln(Tfile[A], Filez.Strings[num_theards]);
Closefile(Tfile[A]);
```

только вместо массива имен `A` я подставил переменную `N` нужного мне результата и приравнял ее к имени файла, чтоб он распознавал, допустим, 1  это `a` и все сработало.

Answer (score 0):

Пример как работать с файлом (тут все вроде бы понятно). ([источник](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TextFile)):

```
var
  myFile : TextFile;
  text   : string;
begin
  // Попытка открыть Test.txt файл для записи
  AssignFile(myFile, 'Test.txt');
  ReWrite(myFile);

  // Запись нескольких известных слов в этот файл
  WriteLn(myFile, 'Hello World');

  // Закрытие файла
  CloseFile(myFile);
end;
```

Ваш код:

```
...
Writeln(Tfile[A], Filez.Strings[num_theards]);
...
```

Что значит `Filez.Strings[num_theards]`? Это массив строк? Нельзя сделать так?:

```
Filez.Strings[num_theards].Text
```